# CodeIgniter routes for user and admin interfaces

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating a website using CodeIgniter, and I want to have an admin interface and a user interface.

Im using this aproach

- controller/

  - admin/dashboard.php
  - admin.php ( loads admin/login.php view )
  - dasboard.php
- models/

  - admin/
- views/

  - admin/dashboard.php, login.php
  - dasboardh.php, login.php

Ok if I go to example.com/admin it works, it loads the login view, but If I want to go to example.com/admin/dashboard it doesn't load.. says page not found

I've tried adding to the routes the followinf route['admin/dashboard']='admin/dashboard'; but it continues not to work. Also in my url's I have always the index.php and I can't take it off with htacess, here is my htaccess:

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on  
php_flag display_errors on  
php_flag html_errors on

RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Every help would be aprecciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For user

```
$route['(inbox|sent|trash)'] = "message/$1";
$route['(settings|change_password|signout)'] = "account/$1";
```

For admin

```
$route['(inbox|sent|trash)'] = "admin/message/$1";
$route['(settings|change_password|signout)'] = "admin/account/$1";
```

make sure that all keys in **$route** should be defined in specified controller

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the admin controller and create a controller with name login inside the admin folder that will work fine. Because Codeigniter look for a method dashboard when you have admin.php controller already.